# Declaring properties and variables in an efficient and readable way?

Tags: php, oop, syntax, properties, standards

To start, I want to make it clear that this is an efficiency and "coding preference" issue -- not a logic or syntax problem.

I'm trying to build a class for my database interactions and logic. In this class, I find myself "defining" the same set of variables three times (in `[Area 1]`, `[Area 2]` and `[Area 3]`).

This seems redundant and misleading -- there must be a better way of doing things, right?

Currently, my code looks something like this:

```php
class db_connection {

   // [Area 1] define properties
   private $db_server;
   private $db_user;
   private $db_password_file;
   private $db_name;

   public function __construct() {
      // [Area 2] give each property a value based on environment variables
      $this->db_server = getenv( 'DB_HOST' );
      $this->db_user = getenv( 'DB_USER' );
      $this->db_password_file = getenv( 'DB_PASSWORD_FILE' );
      $this->db_name = getenv( 'DB_NAME' );
   }

   // create a function to perform connection logic
   public function connect() {

      // [Area 3] give each property a "labeling" variable for readability and ease-of-use
      $db_server = $this->db_server;
      $db_user = $this->db_user;
      $db_password_file = $this->db_password_file;
      $db_name = $this->db_name;

      [...]
```

Here is my reasoning for "defining" in each of my three "Areas":

**[Area 1]**
Declaring properties at the top of a class definition is standard practice. Normally, these properties would also be initialized (with values), but this is not possible here because I want to assign these properties non-constant values using `getenv()`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for more information.

**[Area 2]**
Following my logic for `[Area 1]`, I initialize my properties using my class constructor.

**[Area 3]**
In order to keep my connection logic clean, I gave each one of my properties a local "labeling" variable. I use these properties a lot more in the rest of my code, so having names like `$db_user` vs. `$this->db_user` makes things easier and more readable.

---

This seems like a lot of code for just 4 properties/variables...

Is there a better way of organizing things? What should I be doing differently?

Could defining a constant somewhere, or using the static keyword help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, if the `db_server`, `db_user`, `db_password_file` would not change dynamically at runtime, you'd better define as a `constant` not a `property` in order to get more efficient performance.

As you mentioned, they are read from the `.env` file through the `getenv()` function. Yes, predefined constants or properties are not able to call functions or expressions. If I was you, I would create a connection at the moment of construct.

```
class DBConnection 
{

    /**
     * Connection object
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    public function __construct() 
    {
        // Create a db connection assign to $this->connection
        $this->connection = new PDO(getenv('DB_HOST'), getenv('DB_USER'), ......);
    }

    /**
     * Get all users
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM USER");
    }

}


/**
 * New an instance of DBConnection
 * After that, they are all prepared.
 */
$database = new DBConnection;

/**
 * Call that function to get all users.
 */
$database->getUser();
```

Comment: It may not matter, for the sake of this answer, but I want to clarify just in case: I'm not reading these environment variables from a `.env` file. They are established by my `docker-compose.yml` file and using Docker Secrets. It's kind of the same concept, but just throwing that out there.

Comment: In other words. I use the `environment` options, and not `env_file` in `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: Yes, my point is to simplify a class logic which decreasing unnecessary properties. Back to your questions, `Area 3` is able to use class-level properties directly, no need to assign as a new method-level variable.

Comment: By the way, the part of `connection` instance, you'd better to use `Dependency Inversion Pattern` by `Dependency Injection` trick. That means you should/must to create a connection at another class, then inject the connection instance at the moment of new-ing the class containing query logics. So that your logic class will no longer be coupled with a certain type of connection. Once connection changes (eg. MySQL to PostgreSQL), you need to do is just inject another kind of connections, your logic won't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Areas 1 and 2 look unavoidable. They are as they must be to accomplish that task.

Area 3, however, there is a trick you can use. You can easily define all class variables with local equivalents using the following command:

```
extract(get_object_vars($this));
```

What's happening here is that `get_object_vars()` returns an array of all variables defined on a specified object. In this case, we are targeting `$this`, which is the class instance. It will provide an array of all defined class variables, which then get created as local copies upon passing to `extract()`.

This has the benefit of working cleanly if the values of these class variables need to change. Otherwise, using constants might be prettier.

Comment: This is a great alternative,but it seems less obvious than the other approach. Clever vs. Readable, I think. +1